# d3-geo-voronoi d3-tile polygon fill problem

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, svg, voronoi, vector-tiles

I am trying to use d3-geo-voronoi to display vector tile data using d3-tile. My initial attempt in displaying the data, with fill set to "none" worked, which was very exiting!
[Voronoi tile map without color fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLlAX.jpg)

However, when I attempted to fill the polygons, some of the tiles were distorted.
[Voronoi tile map with color fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18ZKn.jpg)

I've not been able to figure out why this is happening. I checked the svg's in the dom, and everything looks correct. The svg's are correct where there are no polygons, they are just not being rendered properly, possibly they are being covered up. Below is the code I used:

```
const d3 = require('d3');
const d3tile = require('d3-tile');
const d3geovoronoi = require('d3-geo-voronoi');
const vt2geojson = require('@mapbox/vt2geojson');

const pi = Math.PI,
      tau = 2 * pi;

const width = Math.max(960, window.innerWidth),
      height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight);

const map = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "map")
  .style("width", width + "px")
  .style("height", height + "px")
  .on("mousemove", mousemoved);

let projection = d3.geoMercator()
  .scale(1 / tau)
  .translate([0, 0]);

let center = projection([-76.3, 38.794745]);

const tile = d3tile.tile()
  .size([width, height]);

const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1 << 15, 1 << 24])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

const svg = map.append("g")
  .attr("pointer-events", "none")
  .attr("class", "svg");

const info = map.append("g")
  .attr("class", "info");

const ramp = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0.05,0.07]).interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl).range(['#34d8eb','#3a34eb']).unknown("#5c5752")

map.call(zoom)
  .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
    .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
    .scale(1 << 21)
    .translate(-center[0], -center[1]));

function zoomed() {
  let transform = d3.event.transform;

  let tiles = tile(transform);

  let image = svg 
    .style("transform", stringify(tiles.scale, tiles.translate))
    .selectAll(".tile")
    .data(tiles, function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("class", "tile")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width", "0.5")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .style("left", function(d) { return d[0] * 256 + "px"; })
    .style("top", function(d) { return d[1] * 256 + "px"; })
    .each(function(d) { this._xhr = render(d, this); });

  projection
    .scale(transform.k / tau)
    .translate([transform.x, transform.y]);

}

function render(d, xnode) {
  let k = Math.pow(2, d[2]) * 256;
  vt2geojson({
    uri: 'http://localhost:7800/public.r3sim_fort_temp/'+d[2]+'/'+d[0]+'/'+d[1]+'.pbf?properties=node,zeta,mask,bathymetry'
  }, function (err, json) {
    if (err) throw err;
    d3.select(xnode)
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(d3geovoronoi.geoVoronoi().polygons(json).features)
      .enter().append("path")
    //.attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr("fill", function(d) {return ramp(d.properties.site.properties.zeta)})
        .attr("stroke", "#fff")
        .attr("stroke-width", "0.5")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
            .projection(d3.geoMercator()
                .scale(k / tau)
                .translate([k / 2 - d[0] * 256, k / 2 - d[1] * 256])
                .precision(0)));
  })
}

function stringify(scale, translate) {
  const k = scale / 256, r = scale % 1 ? Number : Math.round;
  return "matrix3d(" + [k, 0, 0, 0, 0, k, 0, 0, 0, 0, k, 0, r(translate[0] * scale), r(translate[1] * scale), 0, 1 ] + ")";
}

function mousemoved() {
  info.text(formatLocation(projection.invert(d3.mouse(this)), d3.zoomTransform(this).k));
}

function formatLocation(p, k) {
  const format = d3.format("." + Math.floor(Math.log(k) / 2 - 2) + "f");
  return (p[1] < 0 ? format(-p[1]) + "Â°S" : format(p[1]) + "Â°N") + " "
       + (p[0] < 0 ? format(-p[0]) + "Â°W" : format(p[0]) + "Â°E");
}

<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 V5 Vector Tile Example</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .map {
      background: #5c5752;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .svg {
      position: absolute;
      will-change: transform;
    }
    .tile {
      position: absolute;
      width: 256px;
      height: 256px;
    }
    .info {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10px;
      left: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

In this example I filled the polygons with varying color values. However, the exact same distortions occur if I use a single color value. The distortions are also always in the same place, if I reload all of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I did a deeper dive into the data, and found the bad svg path, and then found the data related to it. It looks like d3.geo.voronoi is producing some bad coordinates, but the input data looks okay. Below are two printouts of node 1192. The first is the input geojson data, showing the coordinates, and the second is the voronoi geometry. The voronoi geometry contains longitude values in the eastern hemisphere (103.86...), which is way outside of the range of the data. I'm still trying to determine why these bad values are being produced. Again, the input coordinates look correct, but possibly it is other data that goes into the voronoi calculation?

```
1192 
{…}
  geometry: {…}
    coordinates: (2) […]
      0: -76.12801194190979
      1: 38.78622954627738
      length: 2
      <prototype>: Array []
    type: "Point"
    <prototype>: Object { … }
  properties: Object { node: 180407, zeta: "NaN", mask: "True", … }
  type: "Feature"
  <prototype>: Object { … }

1192 (11) […]
  0: Array [ 103.86695733932268, -44.964779133003304 ]
  1: Array [ -76.13308210176842, 38.75793814039401 ]
  2: Array [ -76.13020999558496, 38.782688154120585 ]
  3: Array [ -76.12890669699081, 38.78647064351637 ]
  4: Array [ -76.12807302385534, 38.786723650244355 ]
  5: Array [ -76.12754554182737, 38.78651000385868 ]
  6: Array [ -76.12640847594942, 38.78408839960177 ]
  7: Array [ -76.11435851540921, 38.636536130021334 ]
  8: Array [ 103.858096036925, -39.00570100251519 ]
  9: Array [ 103.860092112702, -39.367933188411186 ]
  10: Array [ 103.86695733932268, -44.964779133003304 ]
  length: 11
  <prototype>: []
```